# Вебхук aiogram python

Tags: python, aiogram, webhook

Написал простенького телеграмм бота с функцией приема платежей (использовал сервис продамус)
URL для отправки уведомлений сгенерировал через ngrok
Уведомления от бота доходят со статусом 200
Уведомления от платежной системы всегда приходят с ошибкой (ошибки разные и 404 и 502 и 503) , пробовал генерировать другой url, с другим портом, та же картина, от бота все ок, от сервиса оплаты ошибка
В чем может дать проблема или в каком направлении смотреть?
Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы только начинаю пробовать пайтон, много непонятного

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts